# Java how can I get a row of Json data outside of the for loop

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am using java to create a web service with Json and am really stumped on a particular area. I have a Jsonarray and JsonObject that reads Json in a for loop, but now how can I for example select items in the second row of the Json outside of the for loop? Perhaps an example of my code will help, my json list is dynamic but this is the format

**[{"state":"LA","city":"Kisatchie"},{"state":"KS","city":"Kismet"}]**

Now I read the json above with this code

```
       // the total String has the whole Json data
      JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(total);

              JSONArray jArray = jsonn.getJSONArray("location_update");
            JSONObject jobject = null;
   String city="";String state="";
            JSONArray sss = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                jobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                city+= jobject.getString("city");
                state+= jobject.getString("state");
                sss.put(jobject);
            }
       // How can I for example get Row 2 of Json here outside the for loop
       // Row 2 is this data
       // {state":"KS","city":"Kismet"}
```

I need this because some of that data in the Json above is used for a dropdown selection menu and as soon as the user clicks on an item I would like to show all the information on that row of Json. I obviously have many more Json items than what I displayed above. I do know that this **jobject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);** is numbering items but I do not know how I can pull that out of the for loop any suggestions would be great

Comment: May I suggest something? Don't waste your time with this awkward JSON lib. Use Jackson that is a better, more intuitive and powerful JSON lib for Java.

Comment: I would also add that you should have showed a small subset of the _exact_ data you are feeding into `JSONObject`.  I don't even know how the answers below were able to verify their solutions.

Comment: I will look into Jackson as I have heard a lot about it. Your right I should have posted more of the data, it is just that I am using Android Studio and the data resides in another IDE which I use for a restful api. I will from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Java starts numbering at `0`, selecting the second array element looks like the following:

```
JSONArray jArray = jsonn.getJSONArray("location_update");
JSONObject jobject = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect

Answer (score 1):

If you want the second object in the array:

```
JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(total);
JSONArray jArray = jsonn.getJSONArray("location_update");
jobject = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

If you already have jsonn or jArray in scope, then you only need:

```
jobject = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstration how to do it, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this outside for loop

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

---

By the way I will prefer to use Jackson library and map my json directly to some class. You can refer this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) by @mkyong.

Comment: Yes I just did and solved it and I will convert the Json into Jackson as people are saying it is a lot more useful.

Comment: It depends on what framework you are using. In some frameworks (like Spring-mvc) you can directly map your json to class using jackson by doing some changes.